# Can anyone identify this mark? It is most likely not chinese based

Tags: translation

Can anyone identify this mark?

[image]

Comment: Seems like [](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A5%BE%BE)

Answer (score 0):

Tangho is right, which can be seen by following conventions of the seal script font.  Note this character itself is a variation of 纀, and is a character not well understood with other variations as well.  It has been documented in older texts but isn't common and usually undefined, I would go out on a limb and comfortably assume this mark is a proper noun//name using the character.

Answer (score 0):

It includes 3 characters. They are Chinese ancient hieroglyphics (Oracle).

丝(silk), 草(grass) and 人(human).

**In 人**:
Like a humanoid figure on the side, a long vertical pen represents the human body, and a short diagonal drawing represents the arms. Since the sides are not divided into left and right, it is also possible to write in flip.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you pronounce this?

Comment: @Pedroski It does not mean a specifical character. It just like totem to discribe thing and what happened..

Comment: 丝草的人? 丝草 （学名：Potamogeton pusillus L)

Comment: @Pedroski It could be that person is weaving silk.